# Powershell script to change screen Orientation

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, powershell, orientation, for-loop

I wrote a script to change primary screen orientation to portrait. my screen is 1920X1200
It runs and no error reported. But the screen does not rotated as i expected.

The code was modified from Set-ScreenResolution (Andy Schneider).
Does anybody can help me take a look?

Some reference site:

1. Set-ScreenResolution : 
   http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/2a631d72-206d-4036-a3f2-2e150f297515/
2. C code for change oridentation (MSDN) Changing Screen Orientation Programmatically : 
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx

My Code:

```
Function Set-ScreenOrientation { 



$pinvokeCode = @" 

using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace Resolution 
{ 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public struct DEVMODE1 
    { 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmDeviceName; 
        public short dmSpecVersion; 
        public short dmDriverVersion; 
        public short dmSize; 
        public short dmDriverExtra; 
        public int dmFields; 

        public short dmOrientation; 
        public short dmPaperSize; 
        public short dmPaperLength; 
        public short dmPaperWidth; 

        public short dmScale; 
        public short dmCopies; 
        public short dmDefaultSource; 
        public short dmPrintQuality; 
        public short dmColor; 
        public short dmDuplex; 
        public short dmYResolution; 
        public short dmTTOption; 
        public short dmCollate; 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] 
        public string dmFormName; 

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] 
        public short dmDisplayOrientation

        public short dmLogPixels; 
        public short dmBitsPerPel; 
        public int dmPelsWidth; 
        public int dmPelsHeight; 

        public int dmDisplayFlags; 
        public int dmDisplayFrequency; 

        public int dmICMMethod; 
        public int dmICMIntent; 
        public int dmMediaType; 
        public int dmDitherType; 
        public int dmReserved1; 
        public int dmReserved2; 

        public int dmPanningWidth; 
        public int dmPanningHeight; 
    }; 



    class User_32 
    { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags); 

        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1; 
        public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01; 
        public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1; 
    } 



    public class PrmaryScreenOrientation
    { 
        static public string ChangeOrientation() 
        { 

            DEVMODE1 dm = GetDevMode1(); 

            if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(null, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm)) 
            { 
                dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_90
                dm.dmPelsWidth = 1200; 
                dm.dmPelsHeight = 1920; 

                int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST); 

                if (iRet == User_32.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED) 
                { 
                    return "Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience."; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY); 
                    switch (iRet) 
                    { 
                        case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                            { 
                                return "Success"; 
                            } 
                        case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
                            { 
                                return "You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen.\n If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine\nThen Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode."; 
                            } 
                        default: 
                            { 
                                return "Failed"; 
                            } 
                    } 

                } 


            } 
            else 
            { 
                return "Failed To Change."; 
            } 
        } 

        private static DEVMODE1 GetDevMode1() 
        { 
            DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1(); 
            dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm); 
            return dm; 
        } 
    } 
} 

"@ 

Add-Type $pinvokeCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
[Resolution.PrmaryScreenOrientation]::ChangeOrientation() 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Function Set-ScreenResolutionAndOrientation { 

<# 
    .Synopsis 
        Sets the Screen Resolution of the primary monitor 
    .Description 
        Uses Pinvoke and ChangeDisplaySettings Win32API to make the change 
    .Example 
        Set-ScreenResolutionAndOrientation         
#>

$pinvokeCode = @" 

using System; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace Resolution 
{ 

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public struct DEVMODE 
    { 
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst=32)]
       public string dmDeviceName;

       public short  dmSpecVersion;
       public short  dmDriverVersion;
       public short  dmSize;
       public short  dmDriverExtra;
       public int    dmFields;
       public int    dmPositionX;
       public int    dmPositionY;
       public int    dmDisplayOrientation;
       public int    dmDisplayFixedOutput;
       public short  dmColor;
       public short  dmDuplex;
       public short  dmYResolution;
       public short  dmTTOption;
       public short  dmCollate;

       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
       public string dmFormName;

       public short  dmLogPixels;
       public short  dmBitsPerPel;
       public int    dmPelsWidth;
       public int    dmPelsHeight;
       public int    dmDisplayFlags;
       public int    dmDisplayFrequency;
       public int    dmICMMethod;
       public int    dmICMIntent;
       public int    dmMediaType;
       public int    dmDitherType;
       public int    dmReserved1;
       public int    dmReserved2;
       public int    dmPanningWidth;
       public int    dmPanningHeight;
    }; 

    class NativeMethods 
    { 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode); 
        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE devMode, int flags); 

        public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1; 
        public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01; 
        public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1; 
        public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1;
        public const int DMDO_DEFAULT = 0;
        public const int DMDO_90 = 1;
        public const int DMDO_180 = 2;
        public const int DMDO_270 = 3;
    } 



    public class PrmaryScreenResolution 
    { 
        static public string ChangeResolution() 
        { 

            DEVMODE dm = GetDevMode(); 

            if (0 != NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(null, NativeMethods.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm)) 
            {

                // swap width and height
                int temp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
                dm.dmPelsHeight = dm.dmPelsWidth;
                dm.dmPelsWidth = temp;

                // determine new orientation based on the current orientation
                switch(dm.dmDisplayOrientation)
                {
                    case NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_270;
                        break;
                    case NativeMethods.DMDO_270:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_180;
                        break;
                    case NativeMethods.DMDO_180:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_90;
                        break;
                    case NativeMethods.DMDO_90:
                        dm.dmDisplayOrientation = NativeMethods.DMDO_DEFAULT;
                        break;
                    default:
                        // unknown orientation value
                        // add exception handling here
                        break;
                }


                int iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, NativeMethods.CDS_TEST); 

                if (iRet == NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED) 
                { 
                    return "Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience."; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    iRet = NativeMethods.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, NativeMethods.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY); 
                    switch (iRet) 
                    { 
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                            { 
                                return "Success"; 
                            } 
                        case NativeMethods.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART: 
                            { 
                                return "You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen.\n If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine\nThen Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode."; 
                            } 
                        default: 
                            { 
                                return "Failed To Change The Resolution"; 
                            } 
                    } 

                } 


            } 
            else 
            { 
                return "Failed To Change The Resolution."; 
            } 
        } 

        private static DEVMODE GetDevMode() 
        { 
            DEVMODE dm = new DEVMODE(); 
            dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]); 
            dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm); 
            return dm; 
        } 
    } 
} 

"@ 

Add-Type $pinvokeCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
[Resolution.PrmaryScreenResolution]::ChangeResolution() 
}

Set-ScreenResolutionAndOrientation
```

Comment: How would you modify this to be able to rotate a display other than the Primary?