# Addressing second display in powrshell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I was trying to understand if it is possible to write a cmd/powershell script to control my second display orientation and while resarching i came accros this tread:

[Powershell script to change screen Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644786/powershell-script-to-change-screen-orientation/24346514#24346514)

And a related Git entry that makes implementation easy to use thanks to a cmd script:
https://github.com/Clicketyclick/ChangeScreenOrientation

My question is: This code just manipulates the primary display,I am not to experienced with powershell and even if I tried my best I don´t get to understand in witch part of this code it specified that the display to manipulate is the primary display nor how to modify this script to address my second display instead.

I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Try out the registry setting here? `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\MonitorNameHere\00\00\Rotation` per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60038232/7411885

Comment: Do you know If it is possible to change the register value form Shell?